# magento memory error when i opened localhost/magento/ on xampp

Tags: memory, runtime-error, magento2

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1764582776 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime.php on line 38

Comment: you need to provide code behind this error to get help.

Comment: Try restarting your webserver and clean/flush your magento2 cache.

Comment: no code was there

Comment: i have cleaned/flushed the cache, but this is a temporary solution. after a while the problem again persists

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1764582776 bytes) in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime.php` on line 38

Please check your php.ini setting and memory limit. Kindly increase execution time and memory limit.

Also please add memory limit in your index.php file on the root of magento

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```